# pandas groupby works on series but not on selecting whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Would like to understand this behaviour.

I have a Dataframe `holdings` which has a variety of columns such as

```
[u'date', u'portfolio', u'sector', u'industry', u'instrument', u'name', u'position', u'price', u'pct_chg', u'mv']
```

where `mv` is market value.

When I do

```
holdings['wt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv']) )
```

I get the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in reindexer(value)
   2234 
   2235                     # other
-> 2236                     raise TypeError('incompatible index of inserted column '
   2237                                     'with frame index')
   2238             return value

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

But when I do

```
holdings['wt'] = holdings['mv'].groupby([holdings['holdings.portfolio'],holdings['holdings.date']]).apply(lambda x: x/sum(x) )
```

It works fine.

The former just looks a little neater to me. Have I got the coding wrong or is this expected? Thanks

---

CSV data dump below:

```
',holdings.date,holdings.portfolio,static_data.sector,static_data.industry,holdings.instrument,static_data.name,holdings.position,prices.adjclose,pct_chg,mv\n0,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Health Care Equipment & Services,A,Agilent Technologies Inc,333512000.0,30.61,0.0026203734032099746,10208802320.0\n20072,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,"Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods",RL,Polo Ralph Lauren Corp.,87704000.0,163.35,0.002454740718011772,14326448400.0\n3432,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Information Technology,Semiconductors,BRCM,Broadcom Corporation,592000000.0,33.74,-0.005599764220453829,19974080000.0\n20020,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Drilling,RIG,Transocean,362189000.0,49.65,-0.0028118096003213466,17982683850.0\n19968,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Information Technology,Systems Software,RHT,Red Hat Inc.,187822000.0,54.99,0.009917355371900749,10328331780.0\n3484,2013-01-14 00:00:00,usequity,Health Care,Health Care Equipment & Services,BSX,Boston Scientific,849000.0,6.32,-0.0062893081761006275,5365680.0\n19916,2013-01-14 00:00:00,usequity,Industrials,Industrial Conglomerates,RHI,Robert Half International,60000.0,32.28,0.011278195488721776,1936800.0\n3536,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,Auto Parts & Equipment,BWA,BorgWarner,227373000.0,35.57,0.003668171557562161,8087657610.0\n19864,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Diversified Financial Services,RF,Regions Financial Corp.,1379000000.0,7.06,-0.007032348804500765,9735740000.0\n19812,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Biotechnology,REGN,Regeneron,100390000.0,179.4,-0.00033433634236046395,18009966000.0\n3588,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,REITs,BXP,Boston Properties,153099000.0,100.68,0.003388479170819192,15414007320.000002\n19760,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Staples,Tobacco,RAI,Reynolds American Inc.,531283000.0,39.13,0.0017921146953405742,20789103790.0\n19708,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Industrials,Industrial Conglomerates,R,Ryder System,53039000.0,51.47,0.0027274498344047604,2729917330.0\n3640,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Banks,C,Citigroup Inc.,3029500000.0,42.15,-0.002838892831795725,127693425000.0\n19656,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Exploration & Production,QEP,QEP Resources,180091000.0,29.17,-0.004776526782667934,5253254470.0\n3692,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Information Technology,Systems Software,CA,"CA, Inc.",444906000.0,22.19,0.009554140127388644,9872464140.0\n19604,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Information Technology,Semiconductors,QCOM,QUALCOMM Inc.,1676023000.0,62.05,-0.010208964747168592,103997227150.0\n19552,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Exploration & Production,PXD,Pioneer Natural Resources,143098000.0,111.63,-0.0009844281367460406,15974029740.0\n3744,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Staples,Packaged Foods & Meats,CAG,ConAgra Foods Inc.,424827000.0,29.21,0.0075888237323216146,12409196670.0\n19500,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Materials,Industrial Gases,PX,Praxair Inc.,291372000.0,110.15,0.0009086778736937529,32094625800.0\n19448,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Industrials,Industrial Conglomerates,PWR,Quanta Services Inc.,216795000.0,28.66,-0.012405237767057153,6213344700.0\n3796,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Health Care Distributors & Services,CAH,Cardinal Health Inc.,336000000.0,41.62,0.003133285128946728,13984320000.0\n19396,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,"Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods",PVH,PVH Corp.,82393000.0,117.49,0.002303361201160259,9680353570.0\n3848,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Equipment & Services,CAM,Cameron International Corp.,198303000.0,57.44,-0.0019113814074717128,11390524320.0\n19344,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Refining & Marketing & Transportation,PSX,Phillips 66,553513000.0,49.42,0.015409903431271799,27354612460.0\n19292,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,REITs,PSA,Public Storage,172418000.0,139.16,-0.005005005005005114,23993688880.0\n20124,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Industrials,Industrial Conglomerates,ROK,Rockwell Automation Inc.,137872000.0,82.65,-0.0018115942028984477,11395120800.0\n3900,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Industrials,Construction & Farm Machinery & Heavy Trucks,CAT,Caterpillar Inc.,611500000.0,90.32,-0.005943209333039934,55230679999.99999\n3380,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Health Care Distributors & Services,BMY,Bristol-Myers Squibb,1658776000.0,32.49,0.00277777777777799,53893632240.0\n3328,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Materials,Paper Packaging,BMS,Bemis Company,99880000.0,33.34,0.008469449485783542,3329999200.0000005\n21008,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,Broadcasting & Cable TV,SNI,Scripps Networks Interactive Inc.,140122000.0,58.2,-0.011381009002887632,8155100400.0\n2860,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,Computer & Electronics Retail,BBY,Best Buy Co. Inc.,349615000.0,13.9,0.019061583577712593,4859648500.0\n20956,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Information Technology,Computer Storage & Peripherals,SNDK,SanDisk Corporation,222201000.0,46.04,0.008985316677624366,10230134040.0\n20904,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,Household Appliances,SNA,Snap-On Inc.,58107000.0,77.47,0.0014219234746639664,4501549290.0\n2912,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Health Care Equipment & Services,BCR,Bard (C.R.) Inc.,74898000.0,101.28,-0.004423473901503994,7585669440.0\n20852,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Equipment & Services,SLB,Schlumberger Ltd.,1286793000.0,70.8,-0.01324041811846699,91104944400.0\n2964,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Health Care Equipment & Services,BDX,Becton Dickinson,191835000.0,79.49,0.006584779030011312,15248964149.999998\n20800,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Staples,Packaged Foods & Meats,SJM,Smucker (J.M.),101817000.0,84.88,0.0009433962264151496,8642226960.0\n20748,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Materials,Diversified Chemicals,SIAL,Sigma-Aldrich,119085000.0,75.15,0.0009323388385722442,8949237750.0\n3016,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Diversified Financial Services,BEN,Franklin Resources,622900000.0,44.54,-0.0006730984967466824,27743966000.0\n20696,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Materials,Specialty Chemicals,SHW,Sherwin-Williams,95997000.0,158.08,-0.0006321911746112185,15175205760.000002\n20644,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Materials,Paper Packaging,SEE,Sealed Air Corp.(New),210399000.0,17.77,0.006228765571913986,3738790230.0\n3068,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Equipment & Services,BHI,Baker Hughes Inc,432598000.0,41.06,-0.023078753271472685,17762473880.0\n20592,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Energy,Oil & Gas Refining & Marketing & Transportation,SE,Spectra Energy Corp.,670893000.0,25.99,0.0034749034749035346,17436509070.0\n3120,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Health Care,Biotechnology,BIIB,BIOGEN IDEC Inc.,236155000.0,143.88,0.0006259127894847616,33977981400.0\n20540,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Diversified Financial Services,SCHW,Charles Schwab Corporation,1303355000.0,14.95,-0.0073041168658699585,19485157250.0\n20488,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Utilities,Multi-Utilities & Unregulated Power,SCG,SCANA Corp,142052000.0,43.04,-0.003934274473501587,6113918080.0\n3172,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Banks,BK,The Bank of New York Mellon Corp.,1125709000.0,25.71,-0.002328288707799664,28941978390.0\n20436,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Consumer Discretionary,Restaurants,SBUX,Starbucks Corp.,749500000.0,53.37,-0.006330292310556707,40000815000.0\n3224,2013-01-14 00:00:00,SP500,Financials,Diversified Financial Services,BLK,BlackRock,167610000.0,212.71,0.005340769448908267,35652323100.0\n'
```

Comment: I think you've neglected to pass the `axis=1` param to apply, so it's operating column-wise hence the error. Try: `holdings['wt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv']), axis=1 )`

Comment: For your second code snippet, because you've explicitly selected the column, there is no ambiguity so it succeeds

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @EdChum. Just tried that and got the following error `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' >>
holdings['owt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv']),axis=1 )
`

Comment: Sorry the param is in the wrong scope try this: `holdings['wt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv'], axis=1)  )`

Comment: `holdings['owt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv'],axis=1 ))` gives `TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: and `holdings['owt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply((lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv']),axis=1 ))` gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Hi @EdChum. Sorry no. Both permutations gave errors per my comments above.

Comment: Can you post data to reproduce your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, looking at what you tried:

```
holdings['wt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date']).apply(lambda x: x['mv']/sum(x['mv']) )
```

This fails because you've reduced the number of rows as you are grouping here but trying to assign back to your original df and the indices are no longer compatible.

what you should do is call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) if you want to assign the result of some groupby operation back to your original df:

```
In [174]:

holdings['wt'] = holdings.groupby(['holdings.portfolio','holdings.date'])['mv'].transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
holdings['wt']

Out[174]:
0        0.009482
20072    0.013306
3432     0.018552
20020    0.016702
19968    0.009593
3484     0.734775
19916    0.265225
3536     0.007512
19864    0.009043
19812    0.016728
3588     0.014317
19760    0.019309
19708    0.002536
3640     0.118602
19656    0.004879
3692     0.009170
19604    0.096593
19552    0.014837
3744     0.011526
19500    0.029810
19448    0.005771
3796     0.012989
19396    0.008991
3848     0.010580
19344    0.025407
19292    0.022285
20124    0.010584
3900     0.051298
3380     0.050057
3328     0.003093
21008    0.007574
2860     0.004514
20956    0.009502
20904    0.004181
2912     0.007046
20852    0.084619
2964     0.014163
20800    0.008027
20748    0.008312
3016     0.025769
20696    0.014095
20644    0.003473
3068     0.016498
20592    0.016195
3120     0.031559
20540    0.018098
20488    0.005679
3172     0.026881
20436    0.037153
3224     0.033114
Name: wt, dtype: float64
```

The other thing you did is a little odd really:

```
holdings['wt'] = holdings['mv'].groupby([holdings['holdings.portfolio'],holdings['holdings.date']]).apply(lambda x: x/sum(x) )
```

Instead of passing the column names you've pass a list of 2 series and called this on the column 'mv' which is a series, this creates no grouping as there are no columns to group by forcing it to return a series with an index that is compatible with your original df.

We can test that my `transform` method is the same as your last method:

```
In [178]:

holdings['wt'].equals(holdings['mv'].groupby([holdings['holdings.portfolio'],holdings['holdings.date']]).apply(lambda x: x/sum(x) ))
Out[178]:
True
```